# How to implement PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; in a C# XAML Project with SQLite for Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, zumero

How to implement `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;` in a C# XAML Project with SQLite for Windows Runtime.

After Preparing Database with Zss Manager, It

I tried to implement PRAGMA codes with  the following code snippet

```
public class DbConnection : IDbConnection
{
    string dbPath;
    SQLiteAsyncConnection conn;        

    public DbConnection()
    {
        dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "XYZ.db") ;
        conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

       
    }

    public async Task InitializeDatabase()
    {
        var pragma1 = await conn.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
        var pragma2 = await conn.ExecuteAsync("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;");
```

but I got this error:

> An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in .exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: no such column: OLD.z_rv

Please can anyone help on the pattern to overcome this challenge

Comment: On what line is that exception actually occurring? It doesn't seem like it would be thrown by the `PRAGMA` settings.

Comment: The exception you're describing cannot have come from any of the posted code. Please verify where you got that exception. It's not in the code in the question.

Comment: Also, where did the data in XYZ.db come from? Any tables you're synching to ZSS should be *created* by a ZSS sync. Don't pre-populate or pre-create those tables; that's one way to lead to the error you're seeing.

Comment: The exception was thrown under the SQLite.cs class

Comment: public static IntPtr Prepare2 (IntPtr db, string query)
  {
   IntPtr stmt;
   var r = Prepare2 (db, query, query.Length, out stmt, IntPtr.Zero);
   if (r != Result.OK) {
    throw SQLiteException.New (r, GetErrmsg (db));
   }
   return stmt;
  }

Comment: You should edit the question to include the code throwing the error, preferably including the *call* to `Prepare2`, including the query. And my question about the origin of your local database file is an important one.

Comment: This happen will an update function    item.VatAmount = TotalVat;

                    await oOrderRepository.UpdateOrdersAsync(item); was called. The amazing thing is that I have data in my SQLite database, It have not synced data to the sql server. the zumero sync function was called in the program after the above mentioned update function line. At first run, when Task.Run(() => ZumeroClient.Sync was called, it ran with no changes to sql server database. when a clicked a button to initiate the function again, the error then came up

Comment: Without knowing what's happening in UpdateOrdersAsync(), it's hard to say anything helpful. I'd also be interested in seeing the full ZumeroClient.Sync call -  again, in the question, where it's readable, not here in comments.

Comment: What I suspected was that the zumero sync client did not synchronize, but zumero tables where created at the SQlite Database, and Entries where registered in the zumero.log table in the sql server database. THe way my app is structured to be is that data is first stored at the sqlite database, when the zumero sync function is intiated, it then replicate and sync to sql server and other app clients, when they zumero sync, they get the latest data. You comments might be helpful.

Comment: The code for the zumero sync is :                              string sFilename = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + "XYZ.db";
 string sCipherKey = ValueOrDefault("", null);
 string sServerUrl = ValueOrDefault("http://localhost:8080", null); string sDbfile = ValueOrDefault("osdb", null); string sAuthScheme = ValueOrDefault("", null);string sUser = ValueOrDefault("", null);
 string sPassword = ValueOrDefault("", null);
                await Task.Run(() => ZumeroClient.Sync(sFilename, sCipherKey, sServerUrl, sDbfile, sAuthScheme, sUser, sPassword));

Comment: This is getting lengthy, and I don't want to misunderstand you. You may be better off emailing support@zumero.com. If you *do* wish to include code here, *please* do so in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Zumero along with SQLite-Net (a popular C# ORM layer over SQLite), so you should not call the SQLite-Net `CreateTable<>()` method.  When `CreateTable` is called in an empty database, SQLite-Net will generate and execute the SQL `CREATE TABLE` command.  Unfortunately, this is in direct conflict with Zumero, which expects that on the initial sync, none of the tables that need to be synced down from SQL Server already exist in the SQLite database.  Of course, it be better for Zumero to give a better error than "no such column: OLD.z_rv"

TL;DR:  Don't call `CreateTable` Let Zumero create the table for you when you call Sync.